# How to subscribe multiple phone numbers to a topic under Amazon SNS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

Amazon provides the php example code below to subscribe a number to a topic. However, that only adds *one* number at a time.

How can I add multiple numbers ($endpoint) to the same topic? What would the code need to be at the end?

**PHP Example Code:**

```
<?php
// snippet-start:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.complete]
// snippet-start:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.import]
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
// snippet-end:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.import]

/**
 * Prepares to subscribe an endpoint by sending the endpoint a confirmation message.
 *
 * This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html
 */
 
// snippet-start:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.main]
$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31'
]);

$protocol = 'sms';
$endpoint = '+1XXX5550100';
$topic = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic';

try {
    $result = $SnSclient->subscribe([
        'Protocol' => $protocol,
        'Endpoint' => $endpoint,
        'ReturnSubscriptionArn' => true,
        'TopicArn' => $topic,
    ]);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
} 
// snippet-end:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.main]
// snippet-end:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.complete]
// snippet-sourcedescription:[SubscribeTextSMS.php demonstrates how to send a confirmation message as a text message.]
```

Comment: There is no collection on the request object letting you set many values at once. Therefore based on the REF docs - its a 1-1 call. You need to call subscribe for each number.

Comment: @smac2020 I'm not sure I follow. Can't the sample code be changed to use a list of numbers and add them one by one? Or isn't there a similar method at least?

Comment: There is no option to set a list of numbers or any other collection of numbers. The endpoint is a single String value that you want to receive notifications.

Comment: @smac2020 I understand that. But it's so weird there isn't a way to add more numbers at the same time. I mean, what's the difference between me manually changing the file each time or having a code send the same parameters, except the phone number, block by block?

Comment: You can use a `for` loop and call `subscribe()` once per loop. So, yes, your program can add multiple subscribers, by using multiple `subscribe()` API calls.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Nice, John! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Would you help me adapt the code? I'm afraid I don't have the skills for that =(

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site for asking people to write code for you. If you run into a _specific_ problem, we are happy to answer your questions. The main thing to think about for this code is "where will the phone numbers come from"? It could come from a file, or perhaps it can be passed-into the function.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think that is discussable. This is also a website for learners. Many people have "written" codes for me already, which in fact made me learn a lot - so I guess the final goal was achieved. If you wouldn't like to do that, that's okay, I understand. If you could at least point to a similar example online, or resource, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using a loop still does not get around you can only add 1 endpoint per call. That is all i was trying to suggest. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @smac2020 I added a foreach loop and it worked just fine. I'll post the solution soon. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple. I just needed to add a list of numbers (through an array) and create a foreach loop:

```
<?php
// snippet-start:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.complete]
// snippet-start:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.import]
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient; 
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
// snippet-end:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.import]

/**
 * Prepares to subscribe an endpoint by sending the endpoint a confirmation message.
 *
 * This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html
 */
 
// snippet-start:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.main]
$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31'
]);

$protocol = 'sms';
$endpoints = array('+1XXX5550100', '+2XXX5550100', '+3XXX5550100');
$topic = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic';

foreach ($endpoints as $endpoint) {
    try {
        $result = $SnSclient->subscribe([
            'Protocol' => $protocol,
            'Endpoint' => $endpoint,
            'ReturnSubscriptionArn' => true,
            'TopicArn' => $topic,
        ]);
        var_dump($result);
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    } 
}
// snippet-end:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.main]
// snippet-end:[sns.php.subscribe_text_sms.complete]
// snippet-sourcedescription:[SubscribeTextSMS.php demonstrates how to send a confirmation message as a text message.]
```